# R: How to order items of a list according to another one?

Tags: r, list, sorting

I want to sort the items/objects of one list according to another one. Here a simple example, I have a list of vectors v and a list of matrices m:

```
v <- list(b=c(9,10), a=c(11,12))
m <- list(a=matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2),
          b=matrix(c(5,6,7,8), nrow=2))
```

I tried so far this, with no result:

```
v[order(match(v,m))]
lapply(v, function(x) x[order(match(x,m))])
```

My expected result is:

```
> v
$a
[1] 11 12

$b
[1]  9 10
```

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `names(m)` to subset the `v`

```
v[names(m)]
```